# Podio API sandbox broken: no response but status 500 in console

Tags: podio

Trying to submit a request in Podio API sandbox gives no error nor response, apart from status 500 in the console. Anybody here who can fix it?

Comment: I have same problem and have been in contact with support - they will look into it but cannot promise an ETA. So right now im also looking for a workaround as i cannot use their client library - because i dont have the config details to use it

Comment: I've tried https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360 and it works with no problems. Which method you'are trying to run from sandbox?

Comment: I had problems with at least that very same method you linked to (get item). Now it's working fine for me too. Thanks for the heads up. Maybe the issue is now fixed.